# @Html.DisplayFor - Change background colour from data in Dispaly

Tags: css, razor, background, displayfor

I am quite new to Razor so could be missing something obvious. I have a:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ColourValue, "")
```

that returns a colour value from the model. For Example: **#004080**.

How might I use this ColourValue to change the background and foreground colour of the control?

I am aware I may not be using the correct Html Helper... Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should save the desired color value into another razor variable from the controller, then when you want to have an html element use that value you just place the razor variable, for example:

```
<font color="@ViewBag.color">example</font>
```

or just

```
<font color="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ColourValue, "")">example</font>
```

remember that anything in the view that razor does is just plain text in the eyes of html

Comment: Sorry for huge delay on this... Not sure how it slipped through my net?? How might I then apply this <font> to my @Html.DisplayFor - or do I not use this now with your example?

Comment: Hi, sorry for an even Huge-er dealay ^-^' 

with my first suggestion you would no longer pull from a model, with my second one you just place the displayfor in the color of the font

But just passing the color you want from the controller is easier